# Show that Aff(n) is a matrix Lie group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, lie-groups

Definition: A matrix lie group G is a group of matrices that is closed under nonsingular limits. That is, if A1, A2, A3,... is a convergent sequence of matrices in G, with limit A, and if detA is not 0, then A is in G.

Suppose we take any sequence in Aff(n) such that its limit is an element of $ GL_n(\mathbb{R})$. How do I show that (informally) the limit is in Aff(n)?

Aff(n) is the set of all matrices of the form 
 $$     \begin{pmatrix}
        A & \ b \\
        0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$ where A $\in GL_n(\mathbb{R})$, b in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $0$ is 1 x n zero vector

Note that Aff(n) is a subset of n + 1 by n + 1 matrices

Comment: At some point you may find it useful to know how LaTeX is used.  See my edits to your mathematical notation.  Notice that now ALL of the line beginning with $\operatorname{Aff}(n)=\cdots$ is in MathJax.

Comment: Now you're asking _hard_ questions.  My information on that is old.  I have a copy of _The $\LaTeX$ Companion_ that's well past 10 years old, but still serves me well when I want to look up how to do some things.  Possibly there's a more current edition.  But that's not a book for learning LaTeX from scratch.  I started learning it in about 1994 from a book that came out in 1990 and and was already getting out of date in some ways, and was incomplete in others.  It's called _$\LaTeX$ for Engineers and Scientists_.  There's probably something much better out there.

Comment: I also sometimes look things up on the web using Google.  One can download LaTeX packages that do all sorts of odd things like making it possible to have pages that are partly one column and partly two, or draw Hasse diagrams in LaTeX code.  I've never kept track of which sites I've found these on.  There's also http://tex.stackexchange.com/, where you can post questions.

Answer (score 2):

Your group is isomorphic to the subgroup of $GL(n+1, \mathbb R)$ of matrices of the form $$\begin{pmatrix}A&b\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$ where $A$, $b$, $0$ and $1$ are blocks of sizes $n\times b$, $n\times 1$, $1\times n$ and $1\times 1$, respectively, by an obvious map.

Now this subgroup of $GL(n+1,\mathbb R)$ is the preimage of the vector $(0,\dots,0,1)\in\mathbb R^{n+1}$ under the function $\phi:GL(n+1,\mathbb R)\to\mathbb R^{n+1}$ such that if $B$ is an element of $GL(n+1,\mathbb R)$ then $\phi(B)$ is the last row of $B$.

Since $\phi$ is continuous and $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ Hausdorff, it is clear that your group is a closed subgroup of $GL(n+1,\mathbb R)$. Moreover, you can check easily that the differential of $\phi$ has the correct rank, so in fact it follows at once that the group is in fact a manifold. Etc.

Comment: As you stated the question, it does not make sense: you are trying to compute limits in your group $Aff(n)$ but you did not define a topology on it. This can be done in several ways, but it is always easy to construct Lie groups as closed subgroups of some other Lie group: that is what my argument does.

Comment: That does not make it clearer. It only makes sense to show that your group is closed *in some topological space*, and you have not made that clear.

Comment: Again: no. You simply cannot talk about limits in $Aff(n)$ until you decie what topology you want to put on it (or , alternatively, you view it as a subspace of some other space)

Comment: One way to do this would be: «Consider $Aff(n)$ as a subset of the space of all maps $\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ with the compact-open topology. If $Aff(n)$ closed there?» and yes, it is.

Comment: Well, you defined Aff(n) as a set of functions... and functions are not matrices. You have to pick one.

Comment: if you want to *define* $Aff(n)$ as the set of matrices $\begin{pmatrix}A&b\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ in $GL(n+1,\mathbb R)$, then my answer exactly answers your question.

Comment: I dont really understand your answer. Could you make it less rigorous? (at least for a linear algebra student to understand).

Comment: You want it to be more clear, not less rigurous... I'll rewrite it in a while. But I will rewrite it with a student who knows what a Lie group is in mind, not a linear algebra student!

Comment: Make a list of several subgroups, and then check if they are normal or not! If you add 5 examples of subgroups to the body of the question and still have not found a normal one, I will give you an example.

Comment: @sarah, that works :-)